# Making an Ethernet Shield work with an Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino, ethernet

customer question:

I have had no success with the ethernet & saw some fine print

> Please note that the current design of the ethernet shield is not compatible with the Arduino Mega http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield

Is that correct? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 6):

There is some discussion  [here](http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1239058804/0)  on the Arduino forum (From NKC Electronics) about a fairly simple work around.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just buy [the NKC shield already hacked](http://www.nkcelectronics.com/nkc-ethernet-shield-for-arduino-mega--duemilanove--diecimila-diy-kit.html). I have it, and it works great.